# iOS Customize Local Authentication with Touch ID

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, swift3, touch-id

I am using the following code to implement the touchID/passcode authentication in my app

```
let context : LAContext = LAContext()
    var error: NSError?

    // Check if the device can evaluate the policy.
    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthentication, error: &error) {
        context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthentication,
                                localizedReason: messageString,
                                reply: { (success: Bool, evalPolicyError: Error?) -> Void in

            if success {
                // ...
            }
            else {

                switch evalPolicyError!._code {

                case LAError.systemCancel.rawValue:
                    print("Authentication was cancelled by the system")

                case LAError.userCancel.rawValue:
                    print("Authentication was cancelled by the user")

                case LAError.userFallback.rawValue:
                    print("User selected to enter custom password")
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
                        // ...
                    })

                default:
                    print("Authentication failed")
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
                        // ...
                    })
                }
            }

        })
    }
```

Is is possible to customize it? For example:

1. Choose the number of `TouchID` attempts before switching to passcode?
2. In the first `AlertView` let user choose to switch to passcode with a button (in the current implementation you can access the passcode only if you fail the `TouchID` auth)

Comment: You can set `maxBiometryFailures` https://developer.apple.com/reference/localauthentication/lacontext/1622330-maxbiometryfailures But it is deprecated in iOS 10 so it will stop working at some point